# Exception Thrown: Read Access Violation. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is wrong with my code? I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   **std::basic_string,std::allocator >::c_str**(...) was 0x2210112. occurred

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class card {
private:
  string suit, ranking;
  int sInt = 0, rInt = 0;

public:
  void printCard() { cout << suit << ranking; }
  void printCardInt() { cout << sInt << rInt << endl; }

  // Constructors
  card(string s, string r) {
    setSuit(s);
    setRank(r);
    convert(s, r);
  }

  card() {
    setSuit("NULL");
    setRank("NULL");
  }

  // Returns True if card this is called from is greater than parameter card c
  bool ComparedTo(card c) {
    // if array rank > hand rank
    if (c.getRInt() > getRInt()) {
      return false;
      // if array rank < hand rank
    } else if (c.getRInt() < getRInt()) {
      return true;
      // if array rank == hand rank
    } else if (c.getRInt() == getRInt()) {

      if (c.getSInt() > getSInt()) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  // Returns True if card this is equal to parameter card c
  bool EqualTo(card c) {
    if (c.getRInt() == getRInt()) {
      if (c.getSInt() == getSInt()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Converts string values of Suit and Ranking into int values SInt and RInt
  void convert(string s, string r) {
    // Suit If
    if (getSInt() == 0)
      if (s == "C")
        setSInt(1);
      else if (s == "D")
        setSInt(2);
      else if (s == "H")
        setSInt(3);
      else if (s == "S")
        setSInt(4);

    // Rank If
    if (r == "2")
      setRInt(2);
    else if (r == "3")
      setRInt(3);
    else if (r == "4")
      setRInt(4);
    else if (r == "5")
      setRInt(5);
    else if (r == "6")
      setRInt(6);
    else if (r == "7")
      setRInt(7);
    else if (r == "8")
      setRInt(8);
    else if (r == "9")
      setRInt(9);
    else if (r == "10")
      setRInt(10);
    else if (r == "J")
      setRInt(11);
    else if (r == "Q")
      setRInt(12);
    else if (r == "K")
      setRInt(13);
    else if (r == "A")
      setRInt(14);
  }

  // Getter's and Setter's
  void setSuit(string s) { suit = s; }
  string getSuit() { return suit; }

  void setRank(string r) { ranking = r; }
  string getRank() { return ranking; }

  void setSInt(int s) { sInt = s; }
  int getSInt() { return sInt; }

  void setRInt(int r) { rInt = r; }
  int getRInt() { return rInt; }
};

void putItem(card d[], card c,
             int &length); // insert card into deck in       ascending order
void deleteItem(card d[], card c, int &length); // delete card from deck
void getItem(card d[], card c, int length); // test if card is in deck
void printDeck(card d[], int length); // print all cards in deck

int main() {

  card *deck;
  deck = new card[20];
  card *holdDeck;
  holdDeck = new card[20];
  string data, line, cardinfo, suit, ranks;
  int it1 = 0, it2 = 0;
  int length = 0;
  string name = "DataFile.txt";

  // input data file into one string
  ifstream myfile(name.c_str());
  if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
      line = (line + "\n");
      data += line;
    }
    myfile.close();
  } else {
    cout << "cant find" << endl;
  }

  // Input initial 20 items
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cardinfo = "";
    suit = "";
    ranks = "";
    // Find first ,
    while (data.c_str()[it2] != ',') {
      it2++;
    }

    // Grab Entire Card
    cardinfo = data.substr(it1, it2 - it1);
    // Set Suit
    suit = data.substr(it1, 1);

    ranks = data.substr(it1 + 1, it2 - (it1 + 1));

    holdDeck[i].setSuit(suit);
    holdDeck[i].setRank(ranks);
    holdDeck[i].convert(suit, ranks);
    putItem(deck, holdDeck[i], length);

    it2++;
    it1 = it2;
  }
  printDeck(deck, length);

  // Move to next Line
  while (data.c_str()[it2] != '\n') {
    it2++;
  }
  it2++;
  it1 = it2;
  // start of 2nd line
  /*
  while(data.c_str()[it2]!='\n'){
  while(data.c_str()[it2]!=','){
  it2++;
  }
  //Grab Entire Card
  cardinfo = data.substr(it1,it2-it1);
  //Set Suit
  suit = data.substr(it1,1);
  ranks = data.substr(it1+1,it2-(it1+1));
  /*
  card c(suit,ranks);
  c.convert(suit,ranks);
  deleteItem(deck,c,length);
  //cout<<cardinfo<<endl;
  it2++;
  it1 = it2;
  }
  it2++;
  it1 = it2;
  */
  // Hard Coding Cards
  card a("H", "4");
  card b("D", "5");
  card c("H", "K");
  card d("D", "2");

  // Proving Delete function works
  deleteItem(deck, a, length);
  deleteItem(deck, b, length);
  deleteItem(deck, c, length);
  deleteItem(deck, d, length);

  printDeck(deck, length);

  // Hard Coding put more items
  card e("S", "7");
  card f("H", "K");
  card g("D", "10");

  putItem(deck, e, length);
  putItem(deck, f, length);
  putItem(deck, g, length);

  printDeck(deck, length);

  // Hard coded Cards
  card h("C", "9");

  card i("C", "10");

  // Proof Get Item function works
  getItem(deck, h, length);
  cout << ",";
  getItem(deck, i, length);

  return 0;
}

// Length is not being saved globally
void putItem(card d[], card c, int &length) {
  bool moreToSearch;
  int pos = 0;

  moreToSearch = (pos < length);
  while (moreToSearch) {
    // card is larger than the one in the deck
    if (c.ComparedTo(d[pos])) {
      pos++;
      moreToSearch = (pos < length);
    } else {
      // else is never being called
      moreToSearch = false;
    }
  }
  for (int index = length; index > pos; index--)
    d[index] = d[index - 1];
  d[pos] = c;
  length++;
}

void deleteItem(card d[], card c, int &length) {
  int pos = 0;

  while (!c.EqualTo(d[pos]))
    pos++;

  if (c.EqualTo(d[pos])) {
    for (int index = pos + 1; length > index; index++)
      d[index - 1] = d[index];
    length--;
  }
}

void getItem(card d[], card c, int length) {
  int pos = 0;
  bool moreToSearch = (pos < length);
  while (moreToSearch) {
    if (c.EqualTo(d[pos])) {
      cout << c.getSuit() << c.getRank() << " YES";
      return;
    }
    pos++;
    moreToSearch = (pos < length);
  }

  cout << c.getSuit() << c.getRank() << " NO";
}

void printDeck(card d[], int length) {
  for (int it = 0; it < length; it++) {
    d[it].printCard();
    if (it < length - 1)
      cout << ",";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

I tried fixing the line I think is causing the problem, but the problem still occurs. I don't really understand what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your code is too long but still incomplete. You need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: What does the "DataFile.txt" file look like? What line produces the error?